# Panic in Ink! Smart Contracts

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I want to find out how exactly "revert" works in ink! smart contracts:

1. What happen if we `panic!()` in ink! contracts? IIRC we shouldn't use `panic!()` in runtime.
2. Is there any difference between `panic!()` and returning `Result::Error` in ink! contracts?
3. I don't find any documentation regarding this. Am I missing something? Can anybody give me a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `panic!` reverts the state but it also ends the execution of the current contract call. If your method was called by another contract, that contract will receive a `CalleeTrapped` error instead of the `Result`. If that method was called by the user, then he will receive `ContractTrapped`.
2. `Result` can contain more descriptive errors than `CalleeTrapped`. The `Result` can be handled by the caller contract or can be shown better on the UI side. `CalleeTrapped` means that something was wrong during execution.
3. Returning the `Result` means that the code was executed predictable way. The language(ink! or ask!) encodes the `Result` into bytes and returns it back to the caller. If the result was an error, the code raises the `REVERT` flag at the end of the execution so the state will be reverted(That means that revert of state was initiated by the callee contract). On the caller side, the code decoded the bytes into `Result` and provided a descriptive error.

   If `panic!` or `assert!` was called that ends the execution of the contract immediately. And it is `CalleeTrapped` on `contract-pallet` level. `contract-pallet` reverts the state because the contract failed. That error is returned to the caller.

   More about it you can read in [the discussion](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/641).

Comment: As I check in https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/enum.Error.html. There are `ContractReverted`, `CalleeReverted`. Should developers have an eye on them?

Comment: `CalleeReverted` is used during [the checking of execution result](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/2bccebff7a8fdcc2b35437e9f55e29117dc2c414/crates/env/src/engine/on_chain/impls.rs#L398). If it is reverted we will try to decode the output into the expected type(like `Result`).

Comment: Ok Now I understand the difference between the `Trapped` and `Reverted` variant. Actually, they follow the same semantics of `panic!()` and `Result` in Rust. For new readers, this is what I mean.

When you receive the `Trapped`, the error can be expected (because you intentionally `panic!()` in your contract) or unexpected (because the code you don't control `panic!()`). But overall, we should treat this as unexpected error

When you receive the `Reverted`, this means that your contract handle the error smoothly and it's part of business logic. So the error for this case is expected.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is whether you want to encode additional information for the caller in case of an error happening. In both cases all state is reverted.

If you panic (no matter through which means you emit the panic) then no output is emitted. Pretty logical as there is no way to return anything in case of a panic. Please note that the panic message is written to the debug buffer in case of a debug-contract and can be read by an RPC client during a dry run.

If you return a `Result::Err` from your message then all state is reverted but the the caller decode this `Result::Err` and act on it.

It is important to understand panics between cross contract calls are caught by default. The panic of a callee is returned as an error (`CalleeTrapped`) to the caller and doesn't bubble up by default. So both errors are hand-able. Panics just don't convey any information to the caller about the reason for the error.

Comment: Usually, we use custom error for our contract. But as you said, we may also receive `CalleeTrapped` as `Result::Err` also. So how do we combine that system error with the custom error of the contract in the function signature ` -> Result<>`. Thanks @Alexander

Comment: You don't receive `CallTrapped` if you return `Result::Err`. Only when you trap.

Comment: Sorry but what I mean is that is there any example that handle two cases `CallTrapped` and `Result::Err` for a cross-contract call. This is important because from the caller perspective, we never know what the callee will return. Thanks

Comment: I found the github issue of this. https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1207. Thanks